# Transfer files from android phone to PC automatically

Tags: java, android, windows-8.1

I have an program on PC that sorts and organizes various types of files into a database and does some stuff with this data. It's a hassle to add photos though (Take photo, load to Google drive, download on PC,  add to program) so I'd like to have an app that takes a picture and queues it to be added to the database next time the phone is connected to the desktop.

I can't figure out a way to access my phones root folders in Java though since I can't assign a drive letter to it. I've done some research, and it doesn't appear that my phone (Nexus 4) has that capability without some rooting or modding. Is there any way I can use java to detect when the phone is connected and access root folders?

I know the other option is via a network connection between the two devices, but I have 0 networking knowledge so it seems a bit audacious at this point to attempt that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what you're asking for, since it doesn't do it when you plug the phone into the desktop, take a look at [PushBullet](http://pushbullet.com), you can use it to send anything from your phone to your computer (or any other device for that matter) and viceversa.